# Capture undo, redo and other key events on different Operating systems in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keyevent

Is there any library which can capture key events on any operating system and call the handler based on what action was performed?

For example, `undo` on Windows in <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, but on mac it is <kbd>appleKey/commandkey</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.

So my question is is there any library that can call my undo handler on Windows as well as Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mousetrap seems like a pretty good start point. From there, you can detect the Apple key ('command') and different sequences and make your own custom aliases. Shouldn't be too difficult. :-)

http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: I was kind of thinking a library where i need not know the combination for undo, redo, etc. the library should give a function like addUndoListener and then call my handler, in mousetrap i need to pass cntl+z and command+z to trap the event

Comment: I understand. I'm not sure there is anything like that that is comprehensive, but I still think it should be really easy to create with Mousetrap.